# tp-link TL-WN823N Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.04, tp-link

i just installed Ubuntu 19.04 (was working on windows before) and i bought the tp-link tl-wn823n v2 hoping it would work on ubuntu as it seems for most tp link adapters, but i can't seem to make it work, it works but it's very unstable and works at only 1Mb connection speed.

I tried all other solution i found online but non seem to have any effect. Any help!

lsusb result:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL WN823N RTL8192EU
```

smod | grep cfg – result:

```
cfg80211 671744 2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsmod | grep cfg`

Comment: What about results for `mokutil --sb-state; dkms status; modprobe -c | grep 0109`

Comment: there are a lot, am i looking for particular one!

Comment: I got it working on 19.10 using rtl8192cu